# What is the difference between optirun and primusrun (bumblebee)

Tags: nvidia, gpu, bumblebee

I have installed the Lightworks video editor on Debian Jessie. For best performance it needs to run on a discrete video card with the proprietary driver. A Nvidia GTX 860M in my case. I have installed Bumblebee to switch between video cards as needed. With `optirun` or `primusrun` it is possible to run an application using the Nvidia card.

When I use optirun for Lightworks it crashes after startup. When I use primusrun it doesn't and performance is okay. Why is that? What is the difference between the two?

This question has been [asked before](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197914/how-is-primusrun-different-from-optirun), but remains unanswered.

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/134050/200823) on a different question does allude to a difference, but doesn't explain it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bumblebee, earlier, was using `VirtualGL` as its core and now switched to `Primus` technology.

`optirun` uses VirtualGL and `primusrun` uses the Primus technology. That must be the reason.

**Note:** Though the question was posted long back, the answer would help those want to understand the difference.